# what is the easiest way to finding a match between values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to find the `matching value` between two object values. I can iterate the array each time to get it.

But I am looking for some great simplest way ... any one help me?

here is what i look for :

```
let values = [
  {
    "handlingFee": "0.65",
    "min": "0",
    "max": "50000"
  },
  {
    "handlingFee": "0.60",
    "min": "50000",
    "max": "150000"
  },
  {
    "handlingFee": "0.55",
    "min": "150000",
    "max": "999999999"
  }
];

var findHandlingFee = function(){
    return values[0].handlingFee;
}

findHandlingFee(3000); //handlingFee": "0.65
findHandlingFee(5010); //handlingFee": "0.60"
findHandlingFee(300000); //"handlingFee": "0.55"
```

Comment: `$.inArray` handle this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` method which accepts as parameter a **callback** function.

```js
let values = [ { "handlingFee": "0.65", "min": "0", "max": "50000" }, { "handlingFee": "0.60", "min": "50000", "max": "150000" }, { "handlingFee": "0.55", "min": "150000", "max": "999999999" } ];

var findHandlingFee = function(value){
    return values.find(function(item){
       return item.min <= value && item.max >= value;
    }).handlingFee;   
}

console.log(findHandlingFee(3000)); //handlingFee": "0.65
console.log(findHandlingFee(50010)); //handlingFee": "0.60"
console.log(findHandlingFee(300000));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array#filter method.It will return an array but can customize the return condition

```js
let values = [{
    "handlingFee": "0.65",
    "min": "0",
    "max": "50000"
  },
  {
    "handlingFee": "0.60",
    "min": "50000",
    "max": "150000"
  },
  {
    "handlingFee": "0.55",
    "min": "150000",
    "max": "999999999"
  }
];

function findHandlingFee(val) {
  return values.filter(function(item) {
   // return that object where the val is between max and min value
    return +item.min <= val && +item.max >= val;


  })
}
//[0] since filter return an array,getting only object in 0 index
console.log(findHandlingFee(3000)[0].handlingFee);
```